# How to easily test Spring.io Web Service Tutorial Example! with javascript or ajax or

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, spring, web-services

I'm trying to learn about Web services specially those used over SOAP. I love Spring!! I read the tutorial from here!

http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/sites/2.0/reference/html/tutorial.html

Already tried some Ajax code but nothing really came out! 
This soap test message was generated by soapUI and works good!

```
    function callsoap()
{


var soapMessage =
'<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"\
xmlns:sch="http://mycompany.com/hr/schemas">\
<soapenv:Header/>\
<soapenv:Body>\
  <sch:HolidayRequest>\
    <sch:Holiday>\
        <sch:StartDate>2006-07-03</sch:StartDate>\
        <sch:EndDate>2006-07-04</sch:EndDate>\
     </sch:Holiday>\
     <sch:Employee>\
        <sch:Number>32</sch:Number>\
        <sch:FirstName>ee</sch:FirstName>\
        <sch:LastName>dd</sch:LastName>\
     </sch:Employee>\
  </sch:HolidayRequest>\
</soapenv:Body>\
</soapenv:Envelope>';

$.ajax( "http://localhost:8080/holidayService/holidayService", {

contentType: "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8",
type: "POST", //important
dataType: "xml",
data: soapMessage

});

alert("Called Soap!"); 

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org) is the best thing , if anyone ever came here looking for a test tool!!!